# Programatically Slice up Image into Smaller Parts in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

We have thousands of images on our site that we need sliced up into smaller pieces. The images are screenshots, and have whitespace between the individual screenshots. I'm trying to find a way in .NET to programatically scan through the images and slice them up vertically (it's always vertical not horizontal).

I then need to save out the individual images to our blob storage, which I know how to do once I have the Image object itself. The part I don't know how to do is to scan the original image for whitespace and extract the content areas.

Most of the screenshots are rectangular, I've attached probably the most complex example where there's an overlap and the widths are different. in this example I'd need 5 images to be created from the first, and we use .png format.

Any pointers would be great!

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you want to convert the image into an array of pixels.  Then you you take sections of that array and save that to blobs.

Here's some sample code that I found to save an image to an Array.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("FILENAME.bmp", true);
byte[,] PixelArray = new byte[bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height];

int x,y;

for (x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        PixelArray[x,y] = bitmap.GetPixel(x,y);
    }
}
```